# $\langle \Bbb Q,<\rangle$ is an elementary submodel of $ \langle \Bbb R,< \rangle$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to show that $\langle\Bbb Q,<\rangle$ is an elementary submodel of $\langle\Bbb R,<\rangle$.

I first believed that this problem is quite trivial $-$ I thought all I needed to do was show that $\langle\Bbb Q,<\rangle$ and $\langle\Bbb R,<\rangle$ are elementarily equivalent (which follows since both are dense linear orders without endpoint) and then say that $\Bbb Q$ is obviously contained in $\Bbb R$. However, I'm now questioning myself after examining definitions more closely, in particular those related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253735/is-one-structure-elementary-equivalent-to-its-elementary-extension).

In other words, is it not enough to show that the two models are elementarily equivalent, and one a submodel of the other when trying to show one is an elementary submodel of the other?

Comment: +1 for questioning yourself. Self-critique is hard to come by these days.

Comment: I added the $\langle$, $\rangle$ and $<$ to the title: as written I initially interpreted the question to be in the language of ordered fields...in which case the result is highly false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x,u_1,\dots,u_n)$ be a formula of the language, and suppose that $\exists x\varphi(x,r_1,\dots,r_n)$ is true in the rationals, for specific rationals $r_1,\dots,r_n$. Then by the completeness of the theory, if we let $S$ be the finite collection of order relationships among the $r_i$, then 
$$\forall u_1\cdots \forall u_n\left(S(u_1,\dots,u_n)\longrightarrow \exists x\varphi(x,u_1,\dots,u_n)\right)$$
 is true in the rationals, and hence in the reals. Thus $\exists x\varphi(x,r_1,\dots,r_n)$ is true in the reals. The rest follows from Vaught's Test.

Comment: very clear and concise. Thank you!

Comment: should ∀u1⋯∀un(S(u1,…,un)⟶∃x(x,u1,…,un)) actually read ∀u1⋯∀un(S(u1,…,un)⟶∃xφ(x,u1,…,un)?

Comment: We want $u_i$ in both parts.

Comment: I was more preoccupied with whether or not we wanted a phi in the implied statement?

Comment: Sorry for the typo! Yes, there was a missing $\varphi$. I thought I saw an $r_1,\dots,r_n$ in your comment, and fixated on that. But it looks as if they were $u_i$, certainly are now. I find math not set in TeX hard to read!

Comment: thanks! And yeah I'm so sorry about that. I plan to learn to type in TeX over the next month!

Comment: For a few years it has been almost essential for mathematics, many journals will not accept anything else.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an answer that's almost 6 years old, but I don't understand this argument at all. (1) Vaught's Test doesn't seem relevant, so I assume you mean the Tarski-Vaught test. This allows us to conclude that $\mathbb{Q}\preceq \mathbb{R}$ if we show that for every formula $\varphi(x,y)$ (here $y$ is a tuple of variables) and every tuple $b\in \mathbb{Q}^y$, if $\mathbb{R}\models \exists x\, \varphi(x,b)$, then there is some $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi(a,b)$. But this is quite different from what you've shown. (2) The fact that the displayed sentence...

Comment: ... is true in $\mathbb{Q}$ uses the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is homogeneous (any two tuples satisfying $S$ are conjugate by an automorphism). Since $\varphi$ can be an arbitrary formula, it's not obvious just by using density, so it probably deserves a word of justification. Of course, an argument very similar to the one that shows that this sentence holds in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to prove quantifier elimination, which answers the question immediately, as in tomasz's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to show the fact is to notice that the theory of $\bf Q$, the theory of dense linear orderings without endpoints, is satisfied by $\bf R$ and eliminates quantifiers.

If a theory $T$ eliminates quantifiers, then it is true that if we have two structures $M\subseteq N$ both satisfying $T$, then $M\preceq N$ (that follows from the fact that quantifier-free formulas are absolute, which is an easy exercise).

Therefore, whenever you have a model $M$ such that $\operatorname{Th}(M)$ eliminates quantifiers, and $M$ is a submodel of $N$, then to show that it is elementary it is enough to show that they're elementarily equivalent.

In general, $M\subseteq N\wedge M\equiv N$ is strictly weaker than $M\preceq N$ (as I've mentioned in the other post with the example $M=(2{\bf Z},+),N=({\bf Z},+)$).

Answer (score 6):

No it is not enough to show elementary equivalence and that one is a subset of the other.

What you need to show is that  $$\mathbf{Q} \models \sigma \iff \mathbf{R} \models \sigma$$
for any $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{Q}}$-sentence $\sigma$. (where $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the extension of $\mathcal{L}$ with names for all elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ added in)

**EDIT:** For your problem of showing $\mathbf{Q} \preceq \mathbf{R}$ I would recommend first showing the following lemma:

If $\mathbf{A} \subseteq \mathbf{B}$ and for every finite subset $K \subseteq A$  and $b\in B$ there is an automorphism  $f$ of $\mathbf{B}$ which fixes $K$ and $f(b) \in A$ then $\mathbf{A} \preceq \mathbf{B}$

Comment: thanks! I'm a bit lost with how to go about this and would appreciate any guidance

Comment: @NikKumar I've updated with a suggestion for how to solve this problem in particular.

Comment: thanks! so now it really just boils down to proving the lemma, then showing that the lemma can be applied to our case of Q and R?

Comment: @NikKumar yep thats right

Comment: I haven't yet given proving the lemma much thought, but is it's application to Q and R not trivial? Clearly, for every finite set of Q, there is an automorphism of R that fixes that set, then can map a point b in R to a point in Q? Or am I not understanding this properly?

Comment: @NikKumar yes it is not very hard to apply this to $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, this is why it is a useful lemma for the problem.

Comment: I've been advised to not overdo the comments, but I'd like to confirm -- I believe that I have a proof of the lemma that follows from the tarski vaught criterion. Does it sound like I'm on the right track?

Comment: @NikKumar Yeah, I would show it via the Tarski-Vaught test too.