# Simple example of elementary equivalence clarification

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The wikipedia entry for elementarily equivalent structures says,

> For example, consider the language with one binary relation symbol '<'. The model R of real numbers with its usual order and the model Q of rational numbers with its usual order are elementarily equivalent, since they both interpret '<' as an unbounded dense linear ordering.

What I'm wondering is how two structures $M = (\mathbb{R},\lt)$ and $N = (\mathbb{Q},\lt)$ can satisfy the same first order sentences when $M$ will contain a sentence like $\sqrt{2} < 2,$ whereas $N$ will not since $\sqrt{2}$ is not in its domain. Is this because, as the same wiki article says near the beginning,

> If N is a substructure of M, one often needs a stronger condition. In this case N is called an elementary substructure of M if every first-order σ-formula φ(a1, …, an) with parameters a1, …, an from N is true in N if and only if it is true in M.

and thus, $N$'s status as a substructure of $M$ relieves of it of the requirement to interpret the meaning of irrational numbers like $\sqrt2$?

Comment: Can the squareroot of 2 be characterized by a finite collection of statements involving less than relation?

Comment: $M$ will not "contain a sentence like $\sqrt2<2$". The language to consider for elementary equivalence only has $<$ (and $=$), no constants. The language for elementary substructure also has the constants of $N$ but not $\sqrt2.$ So, elementary submodel is generally stronger than elementary equivalence. In fact, for your $M$ and $N$, it is still true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257639

Comment: Yeah, just because something is in the model doesn't mean that there is something in the language. $1,\sqrt 2,\pi,+\infty$ might be in the model, but there are no constants in the language of $<.$

Comment: @coffeemath Good question, I don't believe so since the only non-logical symbol is the relation "<", the sentences in a satisfiable model would only involve the less than relation "<", like the dense order characterization, "for all x < y there exists a z with x < z < y" without explicitly mentioning a particular value, since there are no constant symbols in the language, is that correct? BTW ty and ty to Anne and Thomas for their answers as well

Comment: @HankIgoe Yes and even if you did use a single constant symbol, let's say $k,$ to denote our usual real number $\pi,$ what I mean is there aren't finitely many statements about this constant $k$ using $<$ which would force it to, say, have the same decimal expansion as does $\pi.$ [whatever decimal expansions might mean in the theory]