# Can a theory with plural quantification have elementary equivalent structures that use different length sequences to satisfy sentences?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, nonclassical-logic

Suppose we have a language $\mathcal{L}$ that is first order but allows for plural quantification, and let $T$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-theory that includes a sentence of the form
$$ \exists\bar{x}\;\phi(\bar{x})$$
Now, suppose we have structure, $\mathcal{M}\models T$, and $\bar{x}\in M^a$ such that $\phi(\bar{x})$. Is it possible to have $\mathcal{N}\models T$ that is elementary equivalent to $\mathcal{M}$ such that for any $\bar{y}\in N^b$ satisfying $\phi(\bar{y})$ it follows that $a\neq b$? In other words, is it possible for there to be two structures satisfying the same conditions, but using different amounts of variables to do so?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by plural quantification?

Comment: @AlexKruckman the ability to quantify over tuples of variables as well as having variably polyadic functions and relations.

Comment: @PrimoPetri I don't disagree with the addition of the non-classical logic tag, but could you elaborate on why you removed the model theory tag?

Comment: Ok, but then if you have polyadic functions and relations, what does it mean for structures to be elementarily equivalent?

Comment: @AlexKruckman are there multiple ways of doing this? It seems apparent that it is the same as before except embeddings are generalized such that they are $\bigcup_{i=0} M^i\to\bigcup_{j=0} N^j$ and an embedding $\alpha:\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ is elementary if $\mathcal{M}\models\phi(\bar{a})\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{N}\models\phi(\alpha(\bar{a}))$

Comment: I asked about elementary equivalence and you answered about elementary embeddings, which is a totally different notion. Anyway, two structures should be elementarily equivalent if they satisfy the same first-order sentences. But first-order logic does not have polyadic symbols. So the question is: what is your notion of "first-order sentence"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman are two structures not elementary equivalent if and only if there exists an elementary embedding? Also, a sentence is a formula without free variables, and I would define a formula but I was clearly under the mistaken impression that there existed a standard formal logic that allowed plural quantification with variably polyadic relations and functions.

Comment: No, for example see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/418871/7062 and the linked duplicate.

Comment: @tox123  Maybe poor judgment (after a quick look up in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Phil.). Feel free to add the tag again!

Comment: Is this a correct reading of your question? Fix a logic $L$ with plural quantifiers and variably polyadic function and relation symbols. Is it possible to have two structures $M$ and $N$ which agree on all $L$-sentences, but for which there is a formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$ satisfied in both structures such that if $M\models \varphi(\overline{a})$ and $N\models \varphi(\overline{b})$, then $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$ have different lengths? [I misinterpreted "elementary equivalent" above to have its usually meaning of agreeing on all *first-order* (not $L$-)sentences.]

Comment: I didn't mean to give you a hard time in the comments above - but I do think that the question is impossible to answer until you specify the logic $L$ exactly. Maybe there is a standard logic with plural quantification with variably polyadic symbols in the philosophical literature, but I'm not aware of it. [Also, in my comments above when I wrote "polyadic", I meant "variably polyadic".]

Comment: @AlexKruckman Your interpretation sounds right to me. I only relatively recently started reading Marker, so model theory on non-classical logics is something that is evidently a little beyond my current knowledge, so I apologize for any confusion there. Also, after doing some research, it seems unlikely that there exists such a standard $L$, and even if I at some point find such an $L$ it would probably be so esoteric as to not really make a good question for this site.